# Annotate causes ProgrammingError: must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have something like this, that represents my model:

```
class Model(DjangoModel):
    created_at = DateTimeField(null=True)
    updated_at = DateTimeField(null=True)
    ...

class Vat(Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    disabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...

class Customer(SomeInheritedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...

class Invoice(Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='invoices')
    creditted_by = models.OnetoOneField(User, related_name='creditee')
    ...

class Account(Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='accounts')
    ...

class Product(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...

class License(Model):
    vat = models.ForeignKey('Vat', null=True)  # Null for imported
    imported = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    maintenance = models.ManyToManyField('Maintenance', related_name="maintenances")

class Maintenance(Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignField(Invoice)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

Then I am trying to generate a report on expired licenses, making sure to get **only** the latest Maintenance object sold to this license.

```
# maintenances__invoice__* filters credited invoices, which we want to exclude
report.licenses = License.objects.filter(
    Q(imported=True, expiry_date__range=(report.start_date, report.end_date)),
    maintenances__invoice__creditted_by__isnull=True,
    maintenances__invoice__creditee__isnull=True
)\
    .distinct()\
    .annotate(max_exp_date=Max('maintenances__end'))\
    .filter(max_exp_date__range=(report.start_date, report.end_date))
```

However I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError at /report-menu/create/
column "v3_vat.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...ummary", "v3_agreement"."file_id", "v3_vat"."id", "v3_vat"."...
                                                             ^
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/report-menu/create/?report_type=5
Django Version: 1.10.6
Postgree Version: 9.5
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
column "v3_vat.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...ummary", "v3_agreement"."file_id", "v3_vat"."id", "v3_vat"."...
                                                             ^
```

**The weird thing**: I have two test and a production environment, but this error only happens in production. I have no problem whatsoever with the other two test environments. I know it has something to do with the database, because I have made a backup, restored it in one of the test environments and the same error popped. But what if they are supposed to be identical?

And why field `v3_vat.created_at`? I am not even mentioning this in my `annotate` function.

Comment: let me guess, you are doing your local development / testing with sqlite

Comment: No. To avoid these problems I have made all environments a replica of the production. So I am also running Postgre in the same exact version.

Comment: that's a bit strange because postgresql always had this behaviour (which is the correct behaviour according to SQL92) regarding GROUP BY. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TLDR; use [only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#only)

> Whenever you call only() it replaces the set of fields to load
>   immediately. The method’s name is mnemonic: only those fields are
>   loaded immediately; the remainder are deferred. Thus, successive calls
>   to only() result in only the final fields being considered:

Django tries to be database agnostic but it isn't easy, because mysql and sqlite in particular have a lot of non standard behavior. One of them centers around aggregation. Whereas postgresql is a lot closer to standards compliance. This is best explained in the mysql [5.7 manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

> SQL92 and earlier does not permit queries for which the select list,
>   HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that
>   are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally
>   dependent on (uniquely determined by) GROUP BY columns.

The problem here is that your query selects all the columns (as is the default with django) but some of them do not have meaningfull values when you use an aggregation. For example you have 100 students in 10 classrooms and each of them have a grade. You select the count of students in each class with an aggregate. You want to show the grade as well. But whose grade do you show?

Thus use the only function limit the columns that are selected by django.

Comment: I tried this. If I try to use `only('id')` it says this to several fields in my License `Field License.product cannot be both deferred and traversed using select_related at the same time.` and if I use `defer('vat')` it says `Field License.vat cannot be both deferred and traversed using select_related at the same time.`.

Comment: This comment is irrelevent becacuse your question doesn't have a select related

Comment: I know. But that appears in the error. Do you think this is a Django bug?

Comment: Far from it. I think it's something hidden inside one of your custom filters like `renewable` or `active`

Comment: I tested without them and still the same problem. I'll remove them from the main question, to simplify things. They are just a simple `filter(reneweable=True)` and `filter(disabled=False)`. My main problem only vanishes if I remove `annotate()`.

Comment: Well you have a few custom models as well. it could be anywhere inside them. My answe does address the question you posted though

Comment: You were right. I had a `select_related()` inside my License custom manager. In there it called for Vat class. Thanks.

Comment: glad to know it's solved. All the best with your project